# <div class="rectangle> </div> </div> <div class=" header ">

Tags: html, css

world! Помогите исправить. divы позеленели, на странице все смешалось.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: и что, ничего не замечаете в первом диве?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По всей видимости кавычку удалили случайно вот тут `class="rectangle"`

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы! Кавычки-все так просто оказалось‍♀️

Comment: Пожалуйста, если помог отметьте пожалуйста ответ как верный, слева от ответа галочка

Comment: отметила_____

Comment: спасибочки =))))